# How to use an attribute of a child class in the superclass constructor?

Tags: java, oop

I have a class A which extends a B class and overrides a method *createBody()* which is called in the parent constructor:

```
public class A extends B {

    SomeClass x = null

    public A(int parameter) {
        super(parameter);
        //do something with atributte x
    }

    createBody() {
       //do some stuff
       //assign attribute x
    }
}


public class B {

    public B(int parameter) {
        //do some stuff
        createBody();
    }

    abstract public void createBody();
}
```

As you can see, the method *createBody()* modifies the *x* attribute. My problem is, the *x* attribute remains *null* once the superclass constructor is finished (when I create an instance of the child class). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This won't compile unless B declares method `createBody()` as either a concrete or abstract method.  Please show the _actual_ code.

Comment: Also why is this method in the child class rather than the parent?

Comment: @JordanKaye Because the B class is being extended several times and every child implements different the method

Comment: @JimGarrison Thank you Jim. I will.

Comment: i marked your question -1 for lack of clarity.  I understand that you might just have some of the terminology confused, (for instance, B is the super-class, and your super-class doesn't appear to be trying to use x, as your title suggests.    Again, you can probably benefit from posting the real code, or an actual example that is such, if you can solve the example you can solve the actual problem.

Comment: No need to. I can see now that this was a theorical error and this simple example shows it. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May I warn you that you are in perilous waters here. As you work on it, you'll probably realize you want to call `createBody` in the *superclass* constructor, but implement it in the subclass. This way you are transferring control to a subclass method before that subclass's initialization has even begun. For example, at that point even a line such as

```
private final String x = "string";
```

has not yet run and x is null. This is an anti-idiom for Java and you should avoid it at all cost.

Answer (score 0):

Your super class has an abstract method

```
`abstract public void createBody();`
```

declare the super class as `abstract` ,since super class must be an abstract class to define abstract methods.

Secondly, you should not make a call to the createBody method from super class constructor
since it may be using variables which could not have been even initialized.

```
//do some stuff
//assign attribute x  <--- never do such stuffs
```